# Installing Perl's WWW::Mechanize::Firefox on OpenSuSE 11.4 - resulting in some annoying errors

Tags: linux, perl, makefile, mechanize, gnu-make

Running OpenSuSE 11.4 - and trying to install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox.

Well I guess that I am missing MAKE (which is obviously GNU make - isn't it?)

See the  following...

```
cpan[1]> install WWW::Mechanize::Firefox
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 09 Dec 2011 00:28:36 GMT
Running install for module 'WWW::Mechanize::Firefox'
Running make for C/CO/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.58.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/C/CO/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.58.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/C/CO/CORION/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CO/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.58.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE

  CPAN.pm: Going to build C/CO/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.58.tar.gz

(Re)Creating lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox/Examples.pm
Can't locate HTML/Selector/XPath.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3 /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/i586-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3 . lib) at ./examples/../lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm line 10.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./examples/../lib/WWW/Mechanize/Firefox.pm line 10.
Compilation failed in require at examples/gen_examples_pod.pl line 32.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite HTML::Selector::XPath 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite MozRepl::RemoteObject 0.27 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Object::Import 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Shell::Command 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Task::Weaken 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for WWW::Mechanize::Firefox
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
---- CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.58.tar.gz ----
    Task::Weaken [requires]
    Object::Import [requires]
    Shell::Command [requires]
    MozRepl::RemoteObject [requires]
    HTML::Selector::XPath [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'Task::Weaken'
Running make for A/AD/ADAMK/Task-Weaken-1.04.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/A/AD/ADAMK/Task-Weaken-1.04.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/A/AD/ADAMK/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AD/ADAMK/Task-Weaken-1.04.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build A/AD/ADAMK/Task-Weaken-1.04.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Task::Weaken
Can't exec "make": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden at /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2026.
  ADAMK/Task-Weaken-1.04.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running install for module 'Object::Import'
Running make for A/AM/AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.002.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/A/AM/AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.002.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/A/AM/AMBRUS/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/A/AM/AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.002.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build A/AM/AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.002.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite MRO::Compat 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for Object::Import
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----     AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.002.tar.gz    ----
    MRO::Compat [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'MRO::Compat'
Running make for F/FL/FLORA/MRO-Compat-0.11.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/F/FL/FLORA/MRO-Compat-0.11.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/F/FL/FLORA/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/F/FL/FLORA/MRO-Compat-0.11.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build F/FL/FLORA/MRO-Compat-0.11.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for MRO::Compat
Can't exec "make": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden at /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2026.
  FLORA/MRO-Compat-0.11.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running make for A/AM/AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.002.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Object-Import-1.002-0gvgp8

  CPAN.pm: Going to build A/AM/AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.002.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'MRO::Compat => 0' for 'AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.002.tar.gz' failed when processing 'FLORA/MRO-Compat-0.11.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Can't exec "make": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden at /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2026.
  AMBRUS/Object-Import-1.002.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running install for module 'Shell::Command'
Running make for F/FL/FLORA/Shell-Command-0.06.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/F/FL/FLORA/Shell-Command-0.06.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/F/FL/FLORA/Shell-Command-0.06.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build F/FL/FLORA/Shell-Command-0.06.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Shell::Command
Can't exec "make": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden at /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2026.
  FLORA/Shell-Command-0.06.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running install for module 'MozRepl::RemoteObject'
Running make for C/CO/CORION/MozRepl-RemoteObject-0.28.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/C/CO/CORION/MozRepl-RemoteObject-0.28.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CO/CORION/MozRepl-RemoteObject-0.28.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build C/CO/CORION/MozRepl-RemoteObject-0.28.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite IPC::Run 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite JSON 2 not found.
Warning: prerequisite MozRepl 0.06 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Task::Weaken 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for MozRepl::RemoteObject
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----  CORION/MozRepl-RemoteObject-0.28.tar.gz ----
    MozRepl [requires]
    IPC::Run [requires]
    Task::Weaken [requires]
    JSON [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'MozRepl'
Running make for Z/ZI/ZIGOROU/MozRepl-0.06.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/Z/ZI/ZIGOROU/MozRepl-0.06.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/Z/ZI/ZIGOROU/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/Z/ZI/ZIGOROU/MozRepl-0.06.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build Z/ZI/ZIGOROU/MozRepl-0.06.tar.gz

*** Module::AutoInstall version 1.03
*** Checking for Perl dependencies...
[Core Features]
- Carp::Clan                   ...missing.
- Class::Accessor::Fast        ...missing.
- Class::Data::Inheritable     ...missing.
- Data::Dump                   ...missing.
- Data::JavaScript::Anon       ...missing.
- File::Spec                   ...loaded. (3.3101)
- Module::Pluggable::Fast      ...missing.
- Net::Telnet                  ...missing.
- Template                     ...missing.
- Template::Provider::FromDATA ...missing.
- Text::SimpleTable            ...missing.
- UNIVERSAL::require           ...missing.
- URI                          ...loaded. (1.58)
==> Auto-install the 11 mandatory module(s) from CPAN? [Y/n] y

*** Since we're running under CPANPLUS, I'll just let it take care
    of the dependency's installation later.
*** Module::AutoInstall configuration finished.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Carp::Clan 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Class::Accessor::Fast 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Class::Data::Inheritable 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Data::Dump 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Data::JavaScript::Anon 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Module::Pluggable::Fast 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Net::Telnet 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Template 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Template::Provider::FromDATA 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite Text::SimpleTable 0 not found.
Warning: prerequisite UNIVERSAL::require 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for MozRepl
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----        ZIGOROU/MozRepl-0.06.tar.gz       ----
    Module::Pluggable::Fast [requires]
    Template::Provider::FromDATA [requires]
    Class::Accessor::Fast [requires]
    Data::Dump [requires]
    Class::Data::Inheritable [requires]
    Text::SimpleTable [requires]
    Template [requires]
    Carp::Clan [requires]
    Data::JavaScript::Anon [requires]
    Net::Telnet [requires]
    UNIVERSAL::require [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'Module::Pluggable::Fast'
Running make for M/MR/MRAMBERG/Module-Pluggable-Fast-0.19.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/M/MR/MRAMBERG/Module-Pluggable-Fast-0.19.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/M/MR/MRAMBERG/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MR/MRAMBERG/Module-Pluggable-Fast-0.19.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build M/MR/MRAMBERG/Module-Pluggable-Fast-0.19.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite UNIVERSAL::require 0 not found.
Writing Makefile for Module::Pluggable::Fast
----  Unsatisfied dependencies detected during  ----
---- MRAMBERG/Module-Pluggable-Fast-0.19.tar.gz ----
    UNIVERSAL::require [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'UNIVERSAL::require'
Running make for M/MS/MSCHWERN/UNIVERSAL-require-0.13.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHWERN/UNIVERSAL-require-0.13.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHWERN/UNIVERSAL-require-0.13.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build M/MS/MSCHWERN/UNIVERSAL-require-0.13.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for UNIVERSAL::require
Can't exec "make": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden at /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2026.
  MSCHWERN/UNIVERSAL-require-0.13.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running make for M/MR/MRAMBERG/Module-Pluggable-Fast-0.19.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Module-Pluggable-Fast-0.19-iMlazZ

  CPAN.pm: Going to build M/MR/MRAMBERG/Module-Pluggable-Fast-0.19.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'UNIVERSAL::require => 0' for 'MRAMBERG/Module-Pluggable-Fast-0.19.tar.gz' failed when processing 'MSCHWERN/UNIVERSAL-require-0.13.tar.gz' with 'make => NO'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
Can't exec "make": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden at /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2026.
  MRAMBERG/Module-Pluggable-Fast-0.19.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Running install for module 'Template::Provider::FromDATA'
Running make for B/BR/BRICAS/Template-Provider-FromDATA-0.12.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/B/BR/BRICAS/Template-Provider-FromDATA-0.12.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/B/BR/BRICAS/CHECKSUMS
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/B/BR/BRICAS/Template-Provider-FromDATA-0.12.tar.gz ok
----    Unsatisfied dependencies detected during   ----
---- BRICAS/Template-Provider-FromDATA-0.12.tar.gz ----
    ExtUtils::MakeMaker [build_requires]
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'ExtUtils::MakeMaker'
Running make for M/MS/MSCHWERN/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.62.tar.gz
Fetching with LWP:
ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHWERN/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.62.tar.gz
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/M/MS/MSCHWERN/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.62.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Going to build M/MS/MSCHWERN/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.62.tar.gz

Using included version of JSON::PP::Compat5006 (1.09) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of version (0.88) as it is newer than the installed version (0.82).
Using included version of ExtUtils::Manifest (1.58) as it is newer than the installed version (1.57).
Using included version of Parse::CPAN::Meta (1.4401) as it is newer than the installed version (1.40).
Using included version of CPAN::Meta::YAML (0.003) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of JSON::PP (2.27104) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of CPAN::Meta (2.112150) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of File::Copy::Recursive (0.38) because it is not already installed.
Using included version of Version::Requirements (0.101020) because it is not already installed.
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for ExtUtils::MakeMaker
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Can't exec "make": Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden at /usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 2026.
  MSCHWERN/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-6.62.tar.gz
  make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make


Running make test
```

Any idea what I need to do to fix these problems?

**update:** many many thanks for the  helpful answers; here some additional informations:

```
cpan[1]> o conf
$CPAN::Config options from '/usr/lib/perl5/5.12.3/CPAN/Config.pm':
    commit             [Commit changes to disk]
    defaults           [Reload defaults from disk]
    help               [Short help about 'o conf' usage]
    init               [Interactive setting of all options]

    applypatch         []
    auto_commit        [0]
    build_cache        [100]
    build_dir          [/root/.cpan/build]
    build_dir_reuse    [0]
    build_requires_install_policy [yes]
    bzip2              [/usr/bin/bzip2]
    cache_metadata     [1]
    check_sigs         [0]
    colorize_debug     undef
    colorize_output    [0]
    colorize_print     undef
    colorize_warn      undef
    commandnumber_in_prompt [1]
    commands_quote     undef
    connect_to_internet_ok [1]
    cpan_home          [/root/.cpan]
    curl               [/usr/bin/curl]
    dontload_hash      undef
    dontload_list      undef
    ftp                [/usr/bin/ftp]
    ftp_passive        [1]
    ftp_proxy          []
    ftpstats_period    undef
    ftpstats_size      undef
    getcwd             [cwd]
    gpg                [/usr/bin/gpg]
    gzip               [/usr/bin/gzip]
    halt_on_failure    [0]
    histfile           [/root/.cpan/histfile]
    histsize           [100]
    http_proxy         []
    inactivity_timeout [0]
    index_expire       [1]
    inhibit_startup_message [0]
    keep_source_where  [/root/.cpan/sources]
    load_module_verbosity [none]
    lynx               []
    make               []
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    make_install_make_command []
    makepl_arg         []
    mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuild_install_build_command [./Build]
    mbuildpl_arg       []
    ncftp              []
    ncftpget           []
    no_proxy           []
    pager              [less]
    password           undef
    patch              []
    patches_dir        undef
    perl5lib_verbosity [none]
    prefer_installer   [MB]
    prefs_dir          [/root/.cpan/prefs]
    prerequisites_policy [follow]
    proxy_pass         undef
    proxy_user         undef
    randomize_urllist  undef
    scan_cache         [atstart]
    shell              [/bin/bash]
    show_unparsable_versions [0]
    show_upload_date   [0]
    show_zero_versions [0]
    tar                [/bin/tar]
    tar_verbosity      [none]
    term_is_latin      [1]
    term_ornaments     [1]
    test_report        [0]
    trust_test_report_history [0]
    unzip              [/usr/bin/unzip]
    urllist           
        0 [ftp://ftp.hosteurope.de/pub/CPAN/]
        1 [ftp://mirror.checkdomain.de/CPAN/]
        2 [ftp://mirror.fraunhofer.de/CPAN/]
        3 [ftp://ftp.u-tx.net/CPAN/]
        4 [ftp://cpan.noris.de/pub/CPAN/]
    use_sqlite         [0]
    username           undef
    version_timeout    [15]
    wait_list          undef
    wget               [/usr/bin/wget]
    yaml_load_code     [0]
    yaml_module        [YAML]
```

look forward to hear from you again !! And ineeed - i cant wait to use mecha on this machine.

Comment: Can you also show your CPAN configuration? (Output of `o conf` in CPAN shell)

Comment: hello choroba - many thanks for the answer - i added some infos . hope this lears up abit . love to hear from you. Greetings.

Comment: well - what do you think if i install gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it, you do indeed need to install GNU `make` on your machine.  If any of those modules needs a C compiler, you'll need to install the C development system - which may be quite a number of packages.

The chances are that if you want to install an alternative `make` program, it will also work.  The easiest one to find, though, will be GNU `make`.

---

One of the key items on your CPAN configuration is 'prerequisite_policy [follow]'; that is the most sensible choice. If a prerequisite module is missing, it will be installed automatically. Your trace shows this happening; some of the modules needed are missing, so it tries to install them before installing WWW::Mechanize::Firefox.

The problem is that it keeps failing to find 'make'.  If you have not got 'make' installed, you need to install it.  If you have it installed, you need it on your PATH.  I do note that your config contains:

```
make               []
make_arg           []
make_install_arg   []
make_install_make_command []
```

My CPAN configuration (actually on MacOS X 10.7.2, but I don't think that matters) includes:

```
make               [/usr/bin/make]
make_arg           []
make_install_arg   [UNINST=1]
make_install_make_command [/usr/bin/make]
```

If you have `make` installed, set at least the two command names to the correct path (might be `/usr/local/bin/make`, perhaps, or `/usr/bin/make`).  The `UNINST=1` bit means that code will remove stuff that is no longer needed (because it is out of date) that is in a different directory than where it is about to install the new stuff.  It is a bit arcane, but I've had it like that for a decade or more, AFAICR.  (Mostly, these days, I use CPANPLUS rather than CPAN.)

Comment: hello Jonathan - many thanks for the answer - i added some infos . hope this lears up abit . love to hear from you. Greetings.